# LP Modeling in RStudio: how to use just one coefficent?

Tags: r, linear-programming

Basically I have an objective function that looks like this:

```
(Price - Cost)*Forecast*{-0.01286432 + (0.983889+0.01286432)/(1+ [(Price / CompetitorPrice)-1)*3.333]/0.6053666)^8.624072)}
```

My problem is that the only thing that can be changed is 'Price', but the solver would assign a coefficent to every element of the objective function.

Is there a way to tell R that I want only a coefficient, to be applyed to 'Price'? Or do I have to manually set the constraints that every other variables' coefficent must be 1?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is not clear what you want. Trying to maximize the profit?

Comment: The expression looks malformed (parentheses don't match). In any case, this looks like a nonlinear function in Price so LP may not be appropriate.